# Do airlines bear responsibility if the shuttle bus is delayed?

Tags: legal, airlines, delays

Some airlines operate shuttle coach services between airport and other cities, like Emirates, Etihad, KLM and Alitalia.

If the connecting flight is missed because of shuttle coach delay, does the airline bear the responsibility? KLM offers free flight arrangement when a bus is delayed, but I don't know the answer.

Comment: Do you mean the bus between the plane and the terminal building? Or some other bus?

Comment: Air Baltic (as an example) offers bus service from various cities to Riga airport to connect with flights. There is a published standard for which bus is required for flights with a certain departure time.

Comment: KLM says it will [change your booking free of charge](https://www.klm.com/travel/nl_en/plan_and_book/timetable_and_network/busservice/index.htm) in the event of a delay. But Les Cars Air France [explicitly disclaims](http://en.lescarsairfrance.com/conditions-generales-transport.html) any liability for traffic delays. Considering that not only are these services both in EU countries and both operated by EU carriers, but that KLM and Les Cars Air Frances are *owned by the same company*, there doesn't seem to be a standard rule. Check with your airline.

Comment: @choster The KLM service is intercity; the Air France service is within Paris. (Air Baltic is also intercity; I think in one case international.)

Comment: The policy would likely come with similar exceptions as flights do.  If the bus breaks down our fault, if traffic or bad weather not our fault, etc

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the airline, but usually it doesn't seem to be the case. If you're late for some reason - that's it, you're late. Most European airlines don't seem to care, unless it can be proven to be airline's fault.

Answer (score 1):

If the delay is due to traffic, weather, terrorism, acts of God, (ie, [force majeure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_majeure)) then there is no liability; if say the bus had a technical fault then it will depend if the bus is operated by the airline or by a third party contractor.

The majority of airlines consider late being late; unless its the airplane that's late - in which case they are bound to compensate you.

I would suggest you check with the individual airline.

Comment: Do you have any references for this?

Comment: Yes it's a standard term in contracts.

Comment: Do you have any such contracts to quote?

Comment: Just read the link.

Comment: The problem with links is that they might change or be down temporarily, no matter what huge site or host. As per the [post on this on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/149926), "Quote relevant material to keep the user from having to click on every link given to get basic information.".